# How to count entry by refrenceName?

Tags: php, mysql

How to count entry by refrenceName?
my sql query is

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(refrenceName)
FROM attendance
where event='4'
GROUP BY refrenceName
HAVING ( COUNT(refrenceName) > 0 )
```

and showing result below

[image]

but how to count? I want Ashish(6), Babli(1)Rebecca(5) pls help me

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT concat(refrenceName,"(",count(refrenceName),")")
FROM attendance
where event='4'
GROUP BY refrenceName
HAVING ( COUNT(refrenceName) > 0 );
```

If you use GROUP_CONCAT for reference name, it will show result as reference name with comma separated values 
(like : Ashish,Ashish,Ashish,Ashish,Ashish,Ashish)

As per your expected output, you want to show only the name-not to be duplicated in the result, along with count.

So Hereby concatnating the referenceName with count(referenceName) as we have already groupped by the same column referenceName.